# How do I combine columns together

Tags: linq, lambda

I have 2 lists that contain different data but have similar columns.
Basically I want to join these lists but then merge the similar columns into 1.

```
var listCombo= List1.Where(a=>DataIds.Contains(a.dataId)).DefaultIfEmpty()
    .Join(List2,
    list1 => list1.key,
    list2 => list2.key,
    (L1,L2) => new
    {
        L2.key,
        L2.dataId,
        L2.dataValue,
        L2.date,
        L1.secId,
        L1.dataId,
        L1.dataValue
    });
```

I'd like to combine the dataId and dataValue columns together.  How do I do that?

So I can just say listCombo.dataId or listCombo.dataValue rather than having to uniquely name them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you're trying to combine the two fields into one. Assuming that you have a `Class`

```
public class List1 {
public int dataId {get;set;}
public string dataValue {get;set;}
public string combinedValue {get;set;}
}
```

No you can use like,

```
var listCombo= List1.Where(a=>DataIds.Contains(a.dataId)).DefaultIfEmpty()
    .Join(List2,
    list1 => list1.key,
    list2 => list2.key,
    (L1,L2) => new List1
    {
       dataId = L2.dataId,
       dataValue = L2.dataValue
       combinedValue =  L2.dataId + " - " L2.dataValue
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use POCO methods for a list1, list2, and a third list which is a combo of both.  I would be sure that if you are combining unlike types you do appropriate casts or if you want complex types you can define them as their own properties or what not.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<A> lisA = new List<A> {new A {AId = 1, AName = "Brett"}, new A {AId = 2, AName = "John"}};
            List<B> lisB = new List<B> {new B { BId = 1, BName = "Doe" }, new B { BId = 2, BName = "Howard" } };

            List<C> lisC = lisA.Join(lisB,
                                     list1 => list1.AId,
                                     list2 => list2.BId,
                                     (L1, L2) => new C
                                         {
                                             CId = L1.AId,
                                             CName = L1.AName + " " + L2.BName
                                         }).ToList();

            lisC.ForEach(
                n => Console.WriteLine(n.CName + "\n")
                );

        }

        public class A
        {
            public int  AId { get; set; }
            public string AName { get; set; }
        }

        public class B
        {
            public int BId { get; set; }
            public string BName { get; set; }
        }

        public class C
        {
            public int CId { get; set; }
            public string CName { get; set; }
        }
```